# Trouble with using cvSnakeImage in iOS

Tags: ios, opencv

```
- (UIImage*) snake:(UIImage *)processingImage :(UIImageView *)contourImage{
CvMat cvMatImage = [processingImage CVGrayscaleMat];
cv::Mat cvMatImage2 = &cvMatImage;
IplImage copy = cvMatImage2;
IplImage* snakeImage = &copy;

cvThreshold(snakeImage, snakeImage, 170, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

float alpha = 0.1;
float beta = 0.5;
float gamma = 0.4;

CvSize size;
size.width = 5;
size.height = 5;

CvTermCriteria criteria;
criteria.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER;
criteria.max_iter = 10000;
criteria.epsilon = 0.1;
CvPoint temp;
std::vector<cv::Point> snakeCurve;
cvSnakeImage(snakeImage, temp, 40, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4, CV_VALUE, size, criteria);
```

}

I have already put #include  as well. When I type the cvsnakeimage, the assistance pop up shown the function. However, when I finished, it shows no function match to call for...balabala....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dear, that's from the legacy module. you probably should avoid that, along with the arcane c-api.

Comment: So I can not use the cvsnakeimage in iOS.....

Comment: you probably still can (if you include the legacy.hpp and the lib), but it won't be there in the next opencv version, so you probably should not

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know any software can allow me import image for active contour testing?